# Improper date format in MongoDB Spring Data query criteria

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have an issue with a MongoDB query that I am having challenges with.  In my class, I have a structure of [instance].events.destination.estimatedDateTime, and the value of estimatedDateTime is an ISO Date (eg. 2014-09-23 21:48:00.000Z).  We are using org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria to append criteria to our query like this:

```
criteria = criteria.and("events.destination.estimatedDateTime").gte(today)
```

When this is generated, it looks like this when evaluated at runtime:

```
"events.destination.estimatedDateTime" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2014-10-28T05:00:00.000Z"} }
```

Unfortunately that is returning no records.  I have taken that same condition and attempted to pull records in RoboMongo, but again there are no results.  However, I have found that when I do the following in RoboMongo, I do indeed get results

```
"events.destination.estimatedDateTime" : { $gte : ISODate("2014-10-28T05:00:00.000Z") }
```

Is there a way using the Criteria class to generate ISODate(date) rather than "$date":date?

Comment: As pointed out in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467130/querying-dates-with-mongo-spring-data-vs-mongos-console-dates you cannot take the query output from Spring Data and run it in the mongo shell (or RoboMongo for that matter).

That probably doesn't answer your question. Is today a java.util.Date? A complete, working example would be helpful here.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  Yes, it is a Date instance: new Date().clearTime().

Comment: @DaveShuck Can you please revert me. How you get solve this error.